# Slow saving of PDF in matplotlib

Tags: python, pdf, matplotlib

I have two different particle sets (it is an [AMUSE](http://amusecode.org/) class, but not of any relevance for the question or answer) of different sizes. The first, smaller, contains roughly 5 million particles (~290 MB). The second 41 million (~2.3 GB). I want to have an XY plot (with `np.histogram2d()`) of both of them, with contour lines. That all works like a charm, but saving the figure of the large dataset as a pdf takes 40 minutes. When I do exactly the same with the first dataset, it takes only 5 seconds.

The functions that I use for this is the one below. I have multiple lines where the time is printed, so I could pinpoint the location where it took so long, and it turned out to be the pyplot.savefig() function. The terminal output is below the code.

```
def hist_plot_x_z_contour(particles, N_reductions = 128):
    time1 = time.time()
    fig= pyplot.figure(figsize=[8,8],dpi=200)
    ax = pyplot.subplot(111)

    extent = [-15,15,-5,5]
    cmap = 'Blues'

    Z, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(particles.x.value_in(units.kpc),particles.z.value_in(units.kpc), bins=200, range=[extent[:2],extent[2:]])
    del(particles)
    Z = np.ma.masked_where(Z<= 0, Z)
    pyplot.imshow(Z.T,origin='low',extent=extent,cmap=cmap,interpolation='nearest',aspect='auto',norm=colors.LogNorm())
    print 'Point 1', time.time() - time1

    cb = pyplot.colorbar()  
    cb.set_label('Amount of Particles')

    #Contourlines
    x = 0.5*(xedges[:-1] + xedges[1:])
    y = 0.5*(yedges[:-1] + yedges[1:])
    print 'Point 2', time.time() - time1
    Y, X = np.meshgrid(y, x)
    levels = np.logspace(0,np.log10(Z.max()), 8 )[2:]
    print 'Point 3', time.time() - time1

    pyplot.contour(X,Y,Z,locator=ticker.LogLocator(), colors='k', levels=levels, lw=2,norm=colors.LogNorm(),vmin=1,vmax =Z.max())
    print 'Point 4', time.time() - time1

    pyplot.xlim(extent[:2])
    pyplot.ylim(extent[2:])
    pyplot.xlabel('X ($kpc$)')
    pyplot.ylabel('Z ($kpc$)')


    print 'Point 5', time.time() - time1
    pyplot.savefig(file_location_for_pictures+ 'xz_contour_%d.pdf' %N_reductions)
    print 'Point 6', time.time() - time1
    return
```

Terminal output (of the large sample):

```
Point 1 20.2287580967
Point 2 21.1261689663
Point 3 21.245880127
Point 4 21.6766190529
Point 5 21.6768140793
Point 6 2436.35565519
```

So it is clear that the most time is between point 5 and 6, roughly 40 minutes. I expected that the histogramming and (to a lesser extent) the contourlines would take up most of the time, but it is not. The resulting image is only 500 kb. I am running this on a computer with 8GB of RAM, and after seeing the time it takes to create the histogram, that is also not the bottleneck.

So my question is, why does it take so long?

Comment: Is it possible that the actual number crunching for `Z` is deferred until the code actually needs to output something to file/screen?  What happens if you `print(Z[0,0])` before point 5?

Comment: That works. At first I thought that was the solution because it printed "--", but that is just because it is an empty value. It just prints the values of Z, so the histogramming is already done before point 5.